# The (window).unload function is never being called in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried with several browsers: chrome, firefox, and internet explorer. My page has the folowing code:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Leaving page');
});
```

and the Leaving page alert never appears when I leave the page. I know the syntax is right because when I change the code to call the load function, simply by removing the "un-" as so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  alert('Leaving page');
});
```

The alert appears fine when the window is loaded, also the console doesn't say anything about it being blocked.I have also tried using onbeforeunload as such:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  alert('Leaving page');
};
```

with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. You simply can't `alert()` from the [`unload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/unload):

> - UI interactions are ineffective (window.open, alert, confirm etc.)

If you're wanting to give the user a chance to change their minds about closing the window, [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) is the correct event. But, you can only `return` the `message` you want to display:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'Leaving already?';
};
```

Comment: `return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');` ?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Nope. http://jsfiddle.net/YLC2P/. At least in Chrome, that just results in "*false*" being the `message` without the `confirm()` ever appearing. In the case of `beforeunload`, the `return` value isn't for cancellation.

Comment: OK, thanks. Was just a thought. I'm using Opera here - absolutely nothing in the unload department works.

Comment: The specification and documentation of this stuff between the DOM, HTML5, MDN and MSDN is a bit of a mess (without looking at documentation for other environments). I guess MDN is as good a place as any, but even there it needs a tidy–up (e.g. does beforeunload apply to the document, window or event interface?).